# Contar filas de arreglo bidimensional

Tags: php

Tengo un arreglo bidimensional `$persona[][]` y quiero saber el número de filas que posee.

He utilizado la función `count()`, pero me cuenta todos los elementos del array, tanto filas como columnas.

Comment: ¿podrías añadir un fragmento del código para ver cómo estas haciendo el count()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Codigo

```
<?php

$persona[0][0] = "Daniela";
$persona[0][1] = "Camila";
$persona[0][2] = "Yuli";
$persona[1][0] = "Mariana";
$persona[2] = "Elefante";
$persona[3] = "Cebra";
$persona[4] = "Aguila";

print contarFilas($persona);

function contarFilas($arreglo){

   $cantidad = 0;

   foreach($arreglo as $elemento){
    $cantidad ++;
   }

   return $cantidad;
}

?>
```

---

#### Resultado

> 5

---

### Explicacion

Teniendo en cuenta los principios de posiciones en el arreglo, entendemos que un arreglo siempre esta definido como:

```
$arreglo[FILA][COLUMNA];
```

Haciendo uso del operador `foreach`, podemos acceder a cada una de las "filas" del arreglo. Y bien, podria usarse para acceder a otros valores, lo único que haremos sera contar cuantas filas obtenemos de dicho arreglo. Usando un operador de incremento.

---

### [Ejemplo en linea!](https://tio.run/##ZY3LCsIwEEXX5iuCdKG4sequPhAfOz9AxMXYTm0gTsI0XYnfXtMUtUWY1T333LGFrevlxhZWiMgil4bgMr36kys53AMp1DBMeiwObAcP9YdmAZ0rrbog/uydgBVQT2qNg8YcyGGXzNs3eOOesAjx9l6134VlRU6mhhzw0Wfl6FMde5pXlDplqF8AZrxrM34KIaWMUv9aZZD54WkSotwwQlp8mxJKGaHGB5JrtMHPmUySxngFj9FVTL/FRPh8s67rNw)